# Sales force authentication not working

Tags: java, rest, salesforce

In salesforce i am trying to auth using my java app and i am unable to do same thing i tried with CURL and rest client and from there i am getting authenticated.

```
7455 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - ===========================request begin================================================
7460 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - URI         : https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
7460 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - Method      : POST
7460 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - Headers     : {Accept=[application/json, application/*+json], Content-Type=[multipart/form-data], Content-Length=[227], Accept-Charset=[big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp]}
7463 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - Request body: grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9szVa2RxsqBbP72ytW..qFwBzMBHMHFuYJLGTBOXKTg5splvJ6fN97dpuOK_EgfdX35O0rbs_yiADWbaC&client_secret=915577796371596316&username=user name&password=password+Securitytoken
7463 [main] INFO com.fm.fixconnector.restclient.LoggingRequestInterceptor - ==========================request end================================================
```

Here is my code

```
public boolean login() throws RestClientException, URISyntaxException{

    HttpHeaders loginHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    loginHeader.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity= new HttpEntity<String>("grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9szVa2RxsqBbP72ytW..qFwBzMBHMHFuYJLGTBOXKTg5splvJ6fN97dpuOK_EgfdX35O0rbs_yiADWbaC&client_secret=915577796371596316&username=username&password=passoword_securityToken",loginHeader);

    restTemplate.exchange(new URI(loginUrl),HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Map.class);
    ResponseEntity<SalesForceLoginResponse> response = null;


    if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED){
        forceLoginResponse = response.getBody();

        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+response.getBody().getAccessToken());
        return true;
    }else{
        logger.error("Unable to authenticate response code "+response.getStatusCode());
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am struggling from last two days but no success. Can you please help me ?

Every time i am getting

```
{"error":"unknown_error","error_description":"retry your request"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass this as VM argument

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```